# How to show selected value of a UIPickerView according to label

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I am trying to show the UIPickerView with a selected value according to the value of a label in the view.

For example if the label value is 2 and when I open the pickerView I want the value two to be selected in the picker. How would this happen?

My code:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

  //res is array
  return [[res objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"choice_name"];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //choiceList is sting
    self.choiceList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<r_PM act='closepos_choice' cl_choice='%d'/>", row];
}

 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
if (pickerLabel == nil) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 30);
    pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0]];

    //EDITED CODE FOR C_X
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:lblOtomatikPozKap.text];
    [f release];

    NSInteger index = [res indexOfObject:myNumber];

    if(index != NSNotFound ){

        [self.pickerView selectRow:index inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    }

    //EDITED FOR AUSTIN
    NSInteger indexOfItem = [res indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"choice_name"] isEqualToString:@"2"];
    }];

    if (indexOfItem != NSNotFound)
    {
    [self.pickerView selectRow:indexOfItem inComponent:1 animated:NO];
    }
 }

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d- %@", row, [[res objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"choice_name"]];

[pickerLabel setText:str];

return pickerLabel;
}

//Not working at all
- (void)selectRow:(UIPickerView*)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a row  by calling this method on `pickerview` `selectRow:inComponent:animated`: 
**Edit:**

You are getting strings from `res`, first you have to add label string to this array so you can have this row in `pickerView`.
 After that in viewWillAppear or any other method where you want call this method.
First get index of that sring/object.

```
NSInteger index=[resindexOfObject:label.text];
```

Now select the row.

```
if(index != NSNotFound ){
 [self.myPicker selectRow:index inComponent:0 animated:NO]
}
```

Comment: Hi C_X, could you give me some more details? Thanks.

Comment: I have tested the code above it is not working. Could help please?

Comment: How did you test this, do you add label text in array and are you put ur code in correct place? it will be better if you show your code...

Comment: why you are adding this method, this is pickerView instance method, just use that, call that method from viewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear or after picker view load data

Comment: Thanks C_X. I have tried both viewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear and passing inside the method but still the picker showing me the first row.

Comment: It should select, check by selecing some hard code row like [self.myPicker selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO] in ViewWillAppear. This will work if you are showing pickerView in new viewcontroller...? if you are showing in same, then you should do this after displaying pickerView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45216/discussion-between-cem-and-c-x)

Answer (score 1):

First, you would get the index of the value you want to select from your data source (the `res` array, in this case). Then, you would call `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` before showing the picker:

```
NSInteger indexOfItem = [res indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"choice_name"] isEqualToString:@"2"];
}];

if (indexOfItem != NSNotFound)
{
    [self.pickerView selectRow:indexOfItem inComponent:1 animated:NO];
}

// Show picker here
```

Comment: Hi austin, is there another way instead of showing the picker in the below according to your code? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to show the picker where the `// Show picker here` comment is; that was just a suggestion. You could do this at any point after you've created the picker, even after you've shown it.

Comment: I am sorry it is not working. Could you help me please?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `if (indexOfItem != NSNotFound)` and check what the index is. Make sure that `res` isn't `nil` or something like that, too.

Comment: It is not passing inside the `indexOfItem` or `IF`

Comment: That means that a matching item was not found. Your don't want to use the hardcoded value `@"2"`, that was also an example, to match your example value in the question. EDIT: Do you mean that it isn't hitting any of this code at all, or just that it isn't hitting the inside of the `if` statement?

Comment: It in not hitting the inside of the `if` statement. Even not hitting inside `indexOfItem`

Comment: You need to put my code somewhere before the picker is presented (`viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, etc), and not in the delegate method.

Comment: I have tried both viewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear and passing inside the method but still the picker showing me the first row while it should show me the 5th row

Comment: Have both the picker and the `res` array been created at the point the code is called?